# makefile: remove duplicate words without sorting

Tags: makefile

Is there a possibility to remove duplicates in a list of words without sorting *in a makefile*?

```
$(sort foo bar lose)
```

does remove duplicates (which is for me the main functionality in this case), but also sorts (for me an unfortunate side effect in this case). I want to avoid that.

[update]

**bobbogo**'s answer works very nicely. Just remember to use `define uniq` for v3.81 and (did not check this) `define uniq =` for later versions.

**larsmans**' answer works very nicely too *if* your record separator is not a space, e.g. if you want to remove duplicates from `_foo_bar_lose_lose_bar_baz_` or the like. Just remember to use the `RS` and `ORS` awk options instead of `tr`, and wrap it all with `$(firstword  $(shell ... ))`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Boring `$eval` based method:

```
define uniq =
  $(eval seen :=)
  $(foreach _,$1,$(if $(filter $_,${seen}),,$(eval seen += $_)))
  ${seen}
endef

w := z z x x y c x

$(info $(sort $w))
$(info $(call uniq,$w))
```

Extremely fiendish make standard library recursive call (*recursive make considered extremely fiendish*?):

```
uniq = $(if $1,$(firstword $1) $(call uniq,$(filter-out $(firstword $1),$1)))
```

It's worth noting that no variables are damaged in this second formulation (see `seen` in the first). **It is preferable** just for that (given the lack of locals in *make*)!

### EDIT

My obscure comment about recursive make above seems to have muddied the waters somewhat.
"Recursive" in the context of this post means *recursive function*.
It really has nothing to do with the execrable *recursive make*.

The latter (recursive) definition of *uniq* is extremely nice, performant, small, and is definitely the one to use.

Comment: I'm sorry, this doesn't seem to work. $(info $(sort $w)) prints out the sorted array, but $(info $(call uniq,$w)) prints out nothing. I find it a very clever solution, however. Perhaps it only requires a small modification?

Comment: @parvus What version of make are you using? `$(eval...)` is relatively recent, though I think the fiendish solution should be relatively portable.

Comment: `define blah =` is even more recent. Maybe just take away the `=`?

Comment: Aha! That did the trick. I'm using make v3.81, and after removing the = when defining the function, it works!

Comment: I couldn't quite get the results I was aiming for - I could only get unique values in the order of their *last* appearance with my method - but using the variable's intermediate value as a register, without conditionals, showed some promise. `$(eval Y:=$(foreach X,$Z,$(eval Y:=$(filter-out $X,$Y) $X))$Y)` -> `"$(Y)"="z y c x"`. As for the comment on 'recursive make', I thought they meant calling make from the Makefile itself (inconsistent globals, lost flags, deadlock, etc.) - not recursive functions or thingsl ike auto-gen dependencies. Lots of things cause reparsing/reevaluation, don't they?

Comment: To make my attempt more clear - each `:=` is as if declaring a new variable, and any inner references evaluate to the old one. So, `Y2:=$(filter-out $X, $Y) $X`, etc. As I realize now, @bobbogo's `uniq` works the same way - my bad.

Comment: Woah, "execrable" wasn't a typo:
"extremely bad or unpleasant."

Comment: In GNU Make 4.3, does it make any difference whether one uses `define blah =` vs `define blah`?

Comment: @antred No it does not. `=` is the default for `define` (this is backwards compatible).

Answer (score 14):

Depends on where you need it and whether you use GNU make. If you just want to uniq the list of target prerequisites, it's as easy as (http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Quick-Reference) :

> The value of $^ omits duplicate prerequisites, while $+ retains them and preserves their order.

So, a rule like

```
exe: $(OBJS)
        $(LD) -o $@ $^
```

will filter duplicates from $(OBJS) automagically, while still leaving order of other items the same.

Answer (score 8):

You could `echo` the words through `awk`:

```
echo foo bar foo baz bar | tr ' ' '\n' | awk '!a[$0]++'
```

Deduping one-liner taken from [catonmat](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/awk1line.txt).

(Don't forget to double the `$` to `$$` in a Makefile.)

Comment: Ok tx! But how can I get the result back in one string? Awk gives the results with newlines, and I need to have the result stored in a variable so I can pass it around.

Comment: @parvus: an extra `| tr '\n' ' '` at the end should do that. (Not very elegant, I admit.)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. It then outputs " baz" without the quotes. Likely since I try this in a stupid DOS shell (with some ported GnuWin32 utilities like awk and tr and such). I haven't tried it out on a linux system, as this operation is needed in a Windows-only environment.

Comment: I think I found a solution: with awk you can change the field- and record separator. If I use: echo foo bar foo baz bar | awk "!a[$0]++" RS=" " ORS=" " , foo bar baz is printed out. (I have to use double quotes, DOS...)

Comment: I'm nearly there: If D:=foo bar baz bar, E:=$(shell echo $(D) | awk '!a[$$0]++' RS=' ' ORS=' ') prints out foo bar baz bar  - apparently due to some missing or extraneous whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me under GNU make v3.82:

```
uniq = $(eval _uniq := $1)$(strip $(foreach _,$(_uniq),$(if $(filter $_,$(_uniq)),$(eval _uniq := $(filter-out $_,$(_uniq)))$_)))
```

It doesn't modify its input by creating a copy in `_uniq`, and it's not recursive.

Comment: Doesn't work! Try the list `a a qa` to see what I mean

Comment: BTW, there is nothing to dislike in the recursive version. It's clean and performant.

Comment: @bobbogo It works now. Agreed, the recursive version is simpler.