# Makefile with runtime dependencies

Tags: c++, c, makefile, gnu-make, gnu

Suppose I have some makefile with a rule for generating sources (simplified example)

```
SRCS = $(shell find src -name "*.c")
OBJS = $(patsubst src/%.c, build/%.o, $(SRCS))

generate-src:
    @echo "int main() {return 0;}" > ./src/x.c

target: generate-src $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o target $(OBJS)

build/%.o: src/%.c
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

When `make target` is run, the following is the error

```
cc -o target  build/x.o
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'build/x.o'
clang: error: no input files
make: *** [target] Error 1
```

This is because when we call `make target`, `$(OBJS)` evaluates to empty since `$(SRCS)` evaluates to empty. Then generate-src is called, creating `src/x.c`. Then `$(CC) -o target $(OBJS)` is called, but this time `$(OBJS)` evaluates to `build/x.o`, which was not created since it was not identified as a dependency of target.

Is there a way to write this makefile such that `$(OBJS)` is evaluated after `generate-srcs` is ran?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing this.

```
SRCSX = $(shell find src -name "*.c")  src/x.c
uniq = $(if $1,$(firstword $1) $(call uniq,$(filter-out $(firstword $1),$1)))
SRCS = $(call uniq, $(SRCSX))
```

(Definition of `uniq` stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144115/makefile-remove-duplicate-words-without-sorting))

Answer (score 0):

You're not creating `generate-src`, but `./src/x.c`, why wouldn't you  (ab)use target mechanism? Something like this (*untested code*):

```
GENERATED_C := ./src/x.c  

SRCS = $(shell find src -name "*.c")
OBJS = $(patsubst src/%.c, build/%.o, $(SRCS))
GENERATED_OBJ := $(patsubst src/%.c, build/%.o, $(GENERATED_C))

target: $(GENERATED_OBJ) $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o target $(OBJS)

build/%.o: src/%.c
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $@ -o $<

$(GENERATED_OBJ): $(GENERATED_C)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

$(GENERATED_C):
    @echo "int main() {return 0;}" > ./src/x.c
```